# Rank graph edges by importance

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-algorithms

I have a graph data structure that represents a rail network. The nodes of the network are the train stations and the edges are the connections between stations.

Running PageRank on this graph gives me a way to rank the stations by importance. But I want to rank the connections between stations, the edges of the graph, by importance.

Is there an appropriate algorithm to do this? Is there a way to reformat the graph so that I can run PageRank for edges?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? There's a rather standard transformation from one graph to another so that edges in one correspond to nodes in the other, and vice versa.

Comment: Are you positive that page rank is a suitable measure of importance in this application?

Comment: PageRank on nodes would mean *how much* they're connected to the rest of the network. What would PageRank mean on edges?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by *importance* before you can decide whether any particular algorithm can calculate it correctly.

Comment: Also, are you sure your data structure is appropriate? Railway lines very often have junctions that aren't at stations. The true structure is often not that there are lines from city A to cities B and C but, rather, there's a line from A to some point X, where there is no station, and from X to B and C. This seems relevant to your notion of importance since, if the line from A to X is blocked, you can't get to B or C.

Comment: [Also posted on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36413632/781723).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  Which site do you want to keep your question open on?